# While checking script with MySQL database, error incorrect email or password

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

When I try to check my login working it shows me this => email and password incorrect. I have entered the same email and password but it's not working fine.

I'm making a login registration form but it's not working properly when I got to the login form

**Regestration.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['usr_id'])) {
  header("Location: index.php");
}

include_once 'db/connect_db.php';

//set validation error flag as false
$error = false;

//check if form is submitted
if (isset($_POST['signup'])) {
  $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
  $cpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['cpassword']);

  //name can contain only alpha characters and space
  if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/",$name)) {
    $error = true;
    $name_error = "Name must contain only alphabets and space";
  }
  if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $error = true;
    $email_error = "Please Enter Valid Email ID";
  }
  if(strlen($password) < 6) {
    $error = true;
    $password_error = "Password must be minimum of 6 characters";
  }
  if($password != $cpassword) {
    $error = true;
    $cpassword_error = "Password and Confirm Password doesn't match";
  }
  if (!$error) {
    if(mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO users(name,email,password) VALUES('" . $name . "', '" . $email . "', '" . md5($password) . "')")) {
      $successmsg = "Successfully Registered! <a href='login.php'>Click here to Login</a>";
    } else {
      $errormsg = "Error in registering...Please try again later!";
    }
  }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="uploads/pix-favicon.ico">  
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <!-- CSS dependencies -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/pix_style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-style.css" />
    <link href="css/animations.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie-fix.css" />
    <![endif]-->
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css" id="pix_page_style"></style>
</head>
<body><div class="pix_section pix_nav_menu pix_scroll_header normal pix-padding-v-10" data-scroll-bg="#fff" id="section_1">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 pix-inner-col col-sm-10 column ui-droppable">
     <div class="pix-content">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default pix-no-margin-bottom pix-navbar-default">
       <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#pix-navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
         <a class="navbar-brand logo-img logo-img-a pix-adjust-height" href="#"><img src="images/main/logo-md.png" alt="OCMS" class="img-responsive pix-logo-img"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="pix-navbar-collapse">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right media-middle pix-header-nav pix-adjust-height" id="pix-header-nav">
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="login.php" class="pix-slight-white">SignIn</a>
          </li>
         </ul>
        </div>
       </div>
      </nav>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 well">
      <form role="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="signupform">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Sign Up</legend>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Full Name" required value="<?php if($error) echo $name; ?>" class="form-control" />
            <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($name_error)) echo $name_error; ?></span>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" required value="<?php if($error) echo $email; ?>" class="form-control" />
            <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($email_error)) echo $email_error; ?></span>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required class="form-control" />
            <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($password_error)) echo $password_error; ?></span>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" required class="form-control" />
            <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($cpassword_error)) echo $cpassword_error; ?></span>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" name="signup" value="Sign Up" class="btn btn-primary" />
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
      <span class="text-success"><?php if (isset($successmsg)) { echo $successmsg; } ?></span>
      <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($errormsg)) { echo $errormsg; } ?></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center">  
    Already Registered? <a href="login.php">Login Here</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 <div class="pix_section pix-padding-v-40" id="section_5">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12 col-sm-7 column ui-droppable">
     <div class="pix-content pix-padding-v-30">
      <span class="pix-black-gray-light"><span class="pix_edit_text"><strong>OCMS</strong> Copyright © 2017 FIZ | All Rights Reserved</span></span>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12 col-sm-5 column ui-droppable">
     <div class="pix-content pix-padding-v-20 text-right">
      <a href="#" class="small-social">
       <i class="pixicon-facebook3 big-icon-50 pix-slight-white"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="small-social">
       <i class="pixicon-twitter4 big-icon-50 pix-slight-white"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="small-social">
       <i class="pixicon-instagram4 big-icon-50 pix-slight-white"></i>
      </a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<!-- Javascript -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/velocity.ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/appear.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/animations.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/plugins.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Login.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="uploads/pix-favicon.ico">  
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <!-- CSS dependencies -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/pix_style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-style.css" />
    <link href="css/animations.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <title>OCMS</title>
    <style type="text/css" id="pix_page_style"></style>
</head>
<body><div class="pix_section pix_nav_menu pix_scroll_header normal pix-padding-v-10" data-scroll-bg="#fff" id="section_1">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 pix-inner-col col-sm-10 column ui-droppable">
     <div class="pix-content">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default pix-no-margin-bottom pix-navbar-default">
       <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#pix-navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
         <a class="navbar-brand logo-img logo-img-a pix-adjust-height" href="#"><img src="images/main/logo-md.png" alt="OCMS" class="img-responsive pix-logo-img"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <?php if (isset($_SESSION['usr_id'])) { ?>
        <li><p class="navbar-text">Signed in as <?php echo $_SESSION['usr_name']; ?></p></li>
        <li><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></li>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="register.php">Sign Up</a></li>
        <?php } ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
       </div>
      </nav>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 well">
      <form role="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="loginform">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Login</legend>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" required class="form-control" />
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Your Password" required class="form-control" />
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" />
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
      <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($errormsg)) { echo $errormsg; } ?></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center">  
    New User? <a href="register.php">Sign Up Here</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 <div class="pix_section pix-padding-v-40" id="section_5">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12 col-sm-7 column ui-droppable">
     <div class="pix-content pix-padding-v-30">
      <span class="pix-black-gray-light"><span class="pix_edit_text"><strong>OCMS</strong> Copyright © 2017 FIZ | All Rights Reserved</span></span>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12 col-sm-5 column ui-droppable">
     <div class="pix-content pix-padding-v-20 text-right">
      <a href="#" class="small-social">
       <i class="pixicon-facebook3 big-icon-50 pix-slight-white"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="small-social">
       <i class="pixicon-twitter4 big-icon-50 pix-slight-white"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="small-social">
       <i class="pixicon-instagram4 big-icon-50 pix-slight-white"></i>
      </a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<!-- Javascript -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/velocity.ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/appear.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/animations.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/plugins.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't rely on the `real_escape_string()` functions to prevent SQL injection, [they alone are not sufficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string). You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either the [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) driver. [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Comment: MD5 is considered broken for security purposes and is not sufficient for password hashing. Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. If you're using a version of PHP prior to 5.5, you can use [this compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in.

Comment: Ibrahim, I have a tutorial in my profile that deals with authentication, perhaps you'd like to take a look. It's based on SQLite, but the principles will translate to other RDBMSs.

Comment: @AlexHowansky: is that boilerplate text about MD5 worth updating? No-one should be using PHP 5.5 these days, might it be worth putting in a remark to mention that?

Comment: @halfer I agree, no-one *should be* using PHP 5.5 these days. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never actually attempt to search for the data in "Login.php". Your from action isn't running any PHP code and therefor nothing happens.

I suggest that you add a database query that searches for the given Username and Password combination and compares it with the input of the user that is attempting to login.